# UNIFY2000(1992年)について

Tags: sql

UNIFY2000(1992年)のことですが、
SQLを使用していたか？していなかったのか？
SQLの代わりにC言語でプログラミングした
覚えがあります。

古い話ですが、1992年ごろのUNIFY2000に詳しい方が
いらっしゃいましたら、回答のほど、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こんな記事 [DataServer,UNIFY2000の西暦2000年対応について](http://www.unify-jp.com/support/faq/dataserver/ds002.htm) があるようですので、こちらの会社 [ユニファイジャパン株式会社](http://www.unify-jp.com/) に問い合わせてみると何か分かるかもしれません。